# pyinstaller no predefined compiler for raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pyinstaller

I want to convert myscript.py to a exexutable file. i am using raspberry pi(raspbian) and python 2.7.

I am issuing the following command

```
sudo pip install PyInstaller
sudo pyinstaller myscript.py
```

after some processing it provides an error

```
Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your
platform. See <http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#building-the-bootloader>
for more details and instructions how to build the bootloader.
```

i go online to build compiler but could not understand the process.
how could i solve this problem?

Comment: See this question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19372/pyinstaller-fails/19390

Comment: At which point in the [PyInstaller Manual](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#building-the-bootloader) are you stuck? People will need to know this.

Comment: 57 INFO: checking EXE
57 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
58 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
After this stage error is showing

Answer (score 9):

## Full Tutorial

After many hours of searching, I got this working. The answer is straightforward, but it is spread across multiple StackExchange answers and GitHub Issues. I put it all together in this tutorial, so I save some hours for the next poor soul.

### Key Takeaways

- `pip` ships PyInstaller with the incorrect architectures. You need to build it yourself for ARM (Raspberry Pi).

### Step by Step

**1. Build the bootloader**

```
git clone https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller 
# Alternatively download the zip from https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases
cd pyinstaller/bootloader
python ./waf distclean all # or python3
cd ../PyInstaller/bootloader/
ls
```

Here you should see `Linux-32bit-arm` and inside of it `run` and `run_d`

**2. Check the bootloader**

```
file Linux-32bit-arm/run

run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a01c65d74d7d8b483800154dcdd4a5d2aad95d5b, stripped
```

If you see the above, you are good so far. However, if you see something like `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386`, that is wrong.

**3. Copy the bootloader**

If you installed PyInstaller with `pip` inside a `venv`, then do this

```
# Replace ${CLONED_PYINSTALLER_PATH} with the path where you git cloned above
# Replace ${PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT} with the path to your project (where you have the venv)

cp -r ${CLONED_PYINSTALLER_PATH}/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm ${PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT}/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/
```

If you installed with apt-get, then do this

```
# !!! Replace python3.5 with your version
cp -r ${CLONED_PYINSTALLER_PATH}/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader
```

### Debugging

Issue

```
SystemError: objcopy Failure: objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `$FILE`
```

Check

```
`file dist/$FILE`
```

If it does not say `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM [...]`, but instead says Intel or x86, the PyInstaller tries to use the incorrect bootloader. If you executed all steps above, try renaming the `Linux-32bit-arm` to just `Linux-32bit`. That seems to have worked for [this user](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2848)

---

Issue

```
gcc not found
```

Solution

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Suspect path for the compilation of bootloader is wrong for your platform

may do this as mentioned in the forum [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=79132)

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader
sudo mv Linux-32bit Linux-32bit-arm
```

For RPI you need to get bootloader... You may cloned pyinstaller [v3.1.1](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/v3.1.1) into your rpi
Same thing, change the directory name for your arm platform after you have build the pyinstaller

```
cd /path/to/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/bootloader
cp -R Linux-32bit Linux-32bit-arm
```

Answer (score 1):

For RPI, please clone the [pyinstaller source code](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git) first and then follow my instructions.

1. Switch to pyinstaller/ bootloader subfolder.
2. Make the bootloader for your OS using the following command:

   `python3.5 ./waf distclean all`
3. Make the Linux-32bit-arm sub-folder in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-package/PyInstaller/bootloader
4. Copy the run and run_d to Linux-32bit-arm:

```
cp pyinstaller/bootloader/build/debug/run_d /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-package/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm/

cp pyinstaller/bootloader/build/release/run /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-package/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm/
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install and create executables, on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (stretch 9.4), by running setup.py. Python version installed is 3.5.3.

1. `git clone https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller`
2. Inside pyinstaller source folder, run `sudo python3 setup.py install`

After, just execute `pyinstaller <source>.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follwing command to install `pyinstaller`:

```bash
$ pip3 install --upgrade pyinstaller --index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```